# 75 соседей на сервере - это нормально?

Tags: ip

Анализируем коммерческий сайт в силу возможностей, встретился такой параметр:
Соседи на сервере, сайты на одном IP:
Всего 75 сайтов
И далее их перечисление.
Среди них только 3 - нашей компании, все остальные - не всегда похожей с нашей тематики, но все - сделаны нашими разрабами, которые нам сейчас сделали апгрейд сайта и с ним происходит полнейшая чушь, но это долгая история.
Прошу, объясните  - то, что с нами сервером пользуется еще десятки компаний, сказывается ли это на работе, индексации или еще чем-то? Как?

Comment: только на физическом уровне(памяти для модулей, место файлам, скорость обработки запросов и т.п.)

Comment: Это нормально и называется "виртуальный хостинг без выделенного ip-адреса". Недорого и удобно. На работу и индексацию не влияет. Но всегда можно заказать у хостера выделенный ip-адрес - не самая дорогая услуга, примерно $150 в год. О преимуществах можно почитать, например, тут - http://colocat.ru/texts/realip.html

Comment: @Равнодушный, и вы верите всему, что написано в этой статье?

Answer (score 2):

на индексации не сказывается никак.

Answer (score 1):

То что 75 сайтов на одном IP ничего не говорит, а вот если хостер с правами доступа начудил, то тогда у всех этих 75 сайтов может быть возможность просмотреть/изменить/скопировать ваши серверные скрипты. Если у вашей компании 3 собственных сайта и компания заботится о сохранности своей информации почему бы не взять виртуальный выделенный сервер.